# How to expand all sections at once in OneNote's document?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-office-2016, microsoft-onenote-2016

I got a `.one` document containing a lot of sections and subsections. I want to convert this document to `.pdf` or other commonly supported file that I could view on my mobile phone. Unfortunately, OneNote's export option allows me to export only these sections that I manually opened by double clicking on them. And as you can see on the picture below, all subsections are collapsed by default.

[image: Click to open the photo]

The question is how I can expand all of the subsections at once, so I could export the document to another file format with all the subsections being visible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can.
I use Alt + Shift + 9 to open all levels from 1 to 9.

`Set your cursor to the top level (Czasy tryby oznajmujacego). 
Alt + Shift + 9`

This then becomes the default state and navigating away from the page, section, book means you'll see your headings expanded when you return.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to expand them all at once unfortunately, although you can close and open sections 1 to 9 individually with ALT + SHIFT and the 1 to 9 number keys.

Comment: Do you mean there's 9 shortcuts that all toggle the expanded/collapsed state?

Comment: No they individually toggle the expanded/collapsed state of sections 1 to 9. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: consider editing your answer to expand on that point a bit.

Comment: I think you can use Alt, Shit 9 to open everything from 1-9, uf your cursor is on the top level. This then becomes the default state.

Answer (score 0):

At least in OneNote 2016 I'm able to collape/expand all sections as follows:

1. Select all (CTRL+A)
2. Collapse (ALT+SHIFT+1)

Answer (score 0):

@penderi, workaholic, Tyler

Since you speak of sections: Are you referring to this part?
[OneNote left navigation panel (notebooks and sections/section groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmZoZ.png)

Because 'Select all (CTRL+A)' seems not to be not available there? For me, this just works for pages and subpages (displayed in the right navigation panel.
[OneNote right navigation panel (pages and subpages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F2SQ.png)

I´m using Microsoft® OneNote® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20278) 32-bit, but also experienced the same behaviour in former versions.

My usecase was to collapse/expand all notebooks at once, opposed as to having to do this separately for each notebook/sectiongroup.

And sorry for posting this as an answer. Unfortunately I´m not allowed to comment on your answers:-(

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help]. So rather focus on getting to 50 reputation, so you can write comments, instead of mis using the answer button.